# Will my double crust for a fresh uncooked chicken pot pie get soggy if left in refrigerator overnight?

Tags: storage

I am making 8 chicken pot pies with a double crust in a 9" round aluminum container as gifts for friends to take home and cook themselves or freeze it.  I will pre-prep the filling on a Friday   and assemble the pies the next day.  I will refrigerate the pies overnight then give them to my friends that following day. Will the bottom crust get soggy overnight and not crisp up when baking?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you can take some insurance out -- blind bake the bottom crusts, then give it an eggwash to protect it from absorbing too much moisture from the filling.

Comment: Unless it is a complex top crust design, could they not be readily "shipped as a kit and user assembled"? And it might be relevant what kind of crust (ice water shortcrust, hot water shortcrust, graham cracker) is used. What I would try if faced with that task is a) coat the inside of the crust with a thin layer of some saturated fat before filling and/or b) cooking the filling in a way that it is already thickened at filling time, if desired texture allows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it'll be fine. I can't elaborate really. It just will be fine it's how people have done it forever.
I do it on a daily basis. As long as everything is cold when you assemble and the pastry is raw, you'll have no issue at all.